# ValueError: Not enough values to unpack in tfds.load

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to Python and Tensorflow. While executing the tfds.load function, I got following error. I have spent hours trying to understand the error, but I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.
I am using following versions: python 3.8, tensorflow 2.3 and tensorflow-datasets 1.2

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-2-41baf13b8c3f> in <module>
    ----> 1 mnistdataset, mnist_info = tfds.load("mnist", 
                with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

```
~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\api_utils.py in 
disallow_positional_args_dec(fn, instance, args, kwargs)
     50     _check_no_positional(fn, args, ismethod, allowed=allowed)
     51     _check_required(fn, kwargs)
---> 52     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
     53 
     54   return disallow_positional_args_dec(wrapped)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\registered.py in load(name, 
split, data_dir, batch_size, in_memory, shuffle_files, download, as_supervised, decoders, with_info, 
builder_kwargs, download_and_prepare_kwargs, as_dataset_kwargs, try_gcs)
    298   if download:
    299     download_and_prepare_kwargs = download_and_prepare_kwargs or {}
--> 300     dbuilder.download_and_prepare(**download_and_prepare_kwargs)
    301 
    302   if as_dataset_kwargs is None:

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\api_utils.py in 
disallow_positional_args_dec(fn, instance, args, kwargs)
     50     _check_no_positional(fn, args, ismethod, allowed=allowed)
     51     _check_required(fn, kwargs)
---> 52     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
     53 
     54   return disallow_positional_args_dec(wrapped)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\dataset_builder.py in 
download_and_prepare(self, download_dir, download_config)
    260     dl_manager = self._make_download_manager(
    261         download_dir=download_dir,
--> 262         download_config=download_config)
    263 
    264     # Currently it's not possible to overwrite the data because it would

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\dataset_builder.py in 
_make_download_manager(self, download_dir, download_config)
    660         force_download=(download_config.download_mode == FORCE_REDOWNLOAD),
    661         force_extraction=(download_config.download_mode == FORCE_REDOWNLOAD),
--> 662         register_checksums=download_config.register_checksums,
    663     )
    664 

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\api_utils.py in 
disallow_positional_args_dec(fn, instance, args, kwargs)
     50     _check_no_positional(fn, args, ismethod, allowed=allowed)
     51     _check_required(fn, kwargs)
---> 52     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
     53 
     54   return disallow_positional_args_dec(wrapped)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\download\download_manager.py in 
__init__(self, download_dir, extract_dir, manual_dir, dataset_name, force_download, force_extraction, 
register_checksums)
    175     self._register_checksums = register_checksums
    176     # All known URLs: {url: (size, checksum)}
--> 177     self._sizes_checksums = checksums.get_all_sizes_checksums()
    178     # To record what is being used: {url: (size, checksum)}
    179     self._recorded_sizes_checksums = {}

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\download\checksums.py in 
get_all_sizes_checksums()
    127   sizes_checksums = {}
    128   for path in _checksum_paths().values():
--> 129     data = _get_sizes_checksums(path)
    130     for url, size_checksum in data.items():
    131       if (url in sizes_checksums and

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\download\checksums.py in 
_get_sizes_checksums(checksums_path)
    117       continue
    118     # URL might have spaces inside, but size and checksum will not.
--> 119     url, size, checksum = line.rsplit(' ', 2)
    120     checksums[url] = (int(size), checksum)
    121   return checksums
```

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: This looks like a bug in TensorFlow datasets. Can you upgrade it?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds 4.2 is the latest version. What is your tensorflow version?

Comment: Thanks. I updated tensorflow-datasets. It worked

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> After upgrading tensorflow-datasets from `1.2` to `4.2`, issue was
> resolved. (paraphrased from Niteya Shah)

Answer (score 0):

I also was having the issues and this would solve the problems:

```
pip install tensorflow-datasets=4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution, create a new environment just with:

```
conda create --name py3-TF2.0 python=3  
conda activate py3-TF2.0      
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-datasets
pip install ipykernel
```