# having problem with tfds.load() oxford data in jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, image-segmentation

dataset, info = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet:3.*.*', with_info=True)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65684487/valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-in-tfds-load It's worked for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the name of the dataset.. The correct dataset name is `oxford_iiit_pet`.

You can follow below code to import the dataset:

```
!pip install tensorflow_datasets

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_dataset as tfds

dataset = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
```

OR

```
(train_ds, val_ds, test_ds), metadata = tfds.load(
    'oxford_iiit_pet',
    split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True,
)
```

OR for dataset visualization `(tfds.as_dataframe)`

```
ds, info = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet', split='train', with_info=True)

tfds.as_dataframe(ds.take(4), info)
```

There are several different ways to load the built-in dataset. Please find the reference [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview#load_a_dataset)